# Refused to load the image 'unsafe:data:.image-type;base64, [base64String]'

Tags: html, content-security-policy

I have a web app running only on our local network. It has a section where image/photo of employee need to show. But i can't load the data and the console always log : Refused to load the image 'unsafe:data:[.image-type];base64, [base64 string]' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: "

Note: Some image/photo is loading but some trigger that error. I'm sure that all the data are **safe to load**. Also, when i try to edit the html (developer mode inspect element) removing the '**unsafe**' word in the src="unsafe:data:...." then image/photo is loaded in the html.

Please help me guys to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to put this meta tag in my header: 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
        img-src 'self' data: ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
        style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *" />

But still not working...

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the images are safe then you can try to use

img-src 'self' data:https:; or img-src 'self' data:http:; based on your protocol.

Hope this helps